# Proving a basis of V + U is a basis for $\frac{V}{U}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is as follows,

Let $\mathbb{U}$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{V}$, and let $x_{1},\cdots, x_{m}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{U}$. Extend this basis for $\mathbb{U}$ to a basis $x_{1},\cdots, x_{m}, x_{m+1}, \cdots, x_{n}$ for $\mathbb{V}$. Prove that $x_{m+1} + \mathbb{U}, \cdots, x_{n} + \mathbb{U}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{V}/\mathbb{U}$.

By definition,

$\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{U} = \left\{v + u : u \in \mathbb{U}\right\}$

and

$\mathbb{V}/\mathbb{U} = \left\{v + \mathbb{U} : v \in \mathbb{V}\right\}$.

My attempt at the question thus far is this,

Since $v + U = \left\{v + u : u \in \mathbb{U}\right\}$ then it follows that  $x_{m+1} + \mathbb{U}, \cdots, x_{n} + \mathbb{U} = x_{m+1} + x_{1}, \cdots , x_{n} + x_{m}$, and since  $x_{1},\cdots, x_{m}$ is a basis for $U$ and $x_{m+1}, \cdots, x_{n}$ is a basis for $V$ then $x_{m+1} + x_{1}, \cdots , x_{n} + x_{m}$ is linearly independent and spans $V/U$. As such, it also forms a basis for $V/U$.

I feel like my proof isn't correct but I'm honestly not sure where to start. I know I need to prove that $x_{m+1} + \mathbb{U}, \cdots, x_{n} + \mathbb{U}$ is linearly independent and spans $V/U$ but I'm not sure how to arrive at that, aside from my above proof. So my question is as follows,

> Is this proof correct? If not where did I go wrong and what do I need to fix?

Comment: No, it does not follow that $x_{m+1}+U=x_{m+1}+x_1$. This conclusion is wrong. You need to show $\sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i(x_i+U)=0+U \implies a_i=0 \forall i$

Comment: Actually, everything in your proof is incorrect. Be careful with the objects. Many of your equations don't even make sense.

Comment: @amsmath Could you elaborate a little bit. Which equations don't make sense? The ones in the proof or the definitions?

Comment: _Quote_: "$x_{m+1} + \mathbb{U}, \cdots, x_{n} + \mathbb{U} = x_{m+1} + x_{1}, \cdots , x_{n} + x_{m}$" Nope. What is that supposed to mean? It's mathematically not defined. _Quote_: "$x_{m+1}, \cdots, x_{n}$ is a basis for $V$" This is wrong. _Quote_: "then $x_{m+1} + x_{1}, \cdots , x_{n} + x_{m}$ is linearly independent and spans $V/U$" These elements are not even contained in $V/U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch of proof:

How to show that $x_1+U, ..., x_n+U$ are linearly independant:

$$\sum_1^n a_i(x_i+U)=0+U \implies (\sum_1^n a_ix_i)+U=0+U \implies \sum_1^n a_ix_i \in U$$

From here on it is straightforward.

How to show that $x_1+U, ..., x_n+U$ spans $V/U$:

Let $v+U \in V/U$. This element can be represented by a $v\in V, v \notin U$. This element can be expressed as linear combination of $x_i+U$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x_{m+1} +U$, ..., $x_{n} +U$ are linearly dependent.  Then there are constants $c_{m+1},\ldots,c_n$ not all zero such that

$$c_{m+1}(x_{m+1} +U) + \cdots + c_{n}(x_{n} +U) = 0 + U$$

So for any $u_i \in U$ we have

$$c_{m+1}(x_{m+1} +u_{m+1}) + \cdots + c_{n}(x_{n} +u_n) = u$$

for some $u \in U$.

Can you see how to get from here to a contradiction?